# "Uncaught TypeError: fn(...).signInAnonymously is not a function" error with firebaseui

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuejs3, firebaseui

I am attempting to use firebaseui with anonymous login but attempting to login with it results in `"Uncaught TypeError: fn(...).signInAnonymously is not a function"`